# How to preserve output and add multiple outputs with Shiny modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to preserve the output from one input and then add more outputs.

Code:

```
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("plotType", "Plot Type",
                  c(Scatter = "scatter", Histogram = "hist")
      ),
      # Only show this panel if the plot type is a histogram
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.plotType == 'hist'",
        selectInput(
          "breaks", "Breaks",
          c("Sturges", "Scott", "Freedman-Diaconis", "[Custom]" = "custom")
        ),
        # Only show this panel if Custom is selected
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.breaks == 'custom'",
          sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min = 1, max = 50, value = 10)
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    x <- rnorm(100)
    y <- rnorm(100)
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$plotType == "scatter") {
        plot(x, y)
      } else {
        breaks <- input$breaks
        if (breaks == "custom") {
          breaks <- input$breakCount
        }
        
        hist(x, breaks = breaks)
      }
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Right now the output from "Scatter" disappears if for instance I select "Histogram". I would like to keep the scatter plot and add the histogram below it, *and I would like to do this indefinitely.*

I tried to do a few things but I didn't know what I needed to look for or learn.

Perhaps, I can add a button called `Insert new plot` which resets the inputs and saves the recently made plot, and then I can choose new inputs and generate a plot, and so on.

I merged two screenshots to create a picture of what I would like to achieve

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to do this indefinitely"?

Comment: By indefinitely, I meant that I would like to keep continuing generating plots. Right now we have a scatter plot and a histogram. I would like to keep generating plots. In your helpful answer, you've created a "plot2" to add a second plot. But I was looking for way to generate multiple number of plots without having to create a new plot output.

Comment: Perhaps, I can add a button called ```Insert new plot``` which resets the inputs and saves the recently made plot, and then I can choose new inputs and generate a plot, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that only shows the histogram when the plottype was selected, but keeps the scatter plot and also the histogram once it was selected. For this I use a second plot output and `req` with a flag if the histogram was already selected.

```
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("plotType", "Plot Type",
                  c(Scatter = "scatter", Histogram = "hist")
      ),
      # Only show this panel if the plot type is a histogram
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.plotType == 'hist'",
        selectInput(
          "breaks", "Breaks",
          c("Sturges", "Scott", "Freedman-Diaconis", "[Custom]" = "custom")
        ),
        # Only show this panel if Custom is selected
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.breaks == 'custom'",
          sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min = 1, max = 50, value = 10)
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      plotOutput("plot_2")
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    x <- rnorm(100)
    y <- rnorm(100)
    hist_flag <- FALSE
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      
        plot(x, y)
    })
    
    output$plot_2 <- renderPlot({
      req(input$plotType == "hist" || hist_flag)
      breaks <- input$breaks
      if (breaks == "custom") {
        breaks <- input$breakCount
      }
      
      hist_flag <<- TRUE
      hist(x, breaks = breaks)
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

---

## Edit

The scenario you describe is a good use-case for modules. I've created a module that contains all the logic and ui to output one plot, and then add another module every time one clicks the button:

```
library(shiny)

one_plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  plotOutput(ns("plot"))
}

one_plot <- function(id, x, y, type, breaks, break_counts) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        if (type == "scatter") {
          plot(x, y)
        } else {
          if (breaks == "custom") {
            breaks <- break_counts
          }
          hist(x, breaks = breaks)
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("plotType", "Plot Type",
                c(Scatter = "scatter", Histogram = "hist")
    ),
    # Only show this panel if the plot type is a histogram
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.plotType == 'hist'",
      selectInput(
        "breaks", "Breaks",
        c("Sturges", "Scott", "Freedman-Diaconis", "[Custom]" = "custom")
      ),
      # Only show this panel if Custom is selected
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.breaks == 'custom'",
        sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min = 1, max = 50, value = 10)
      )
    ),
    actionButton("make_plot", "Insert new plot")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    div(id = "add_here")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- rnorm(100)
  y <- rnorm(100)
  counter_plots <- 1
  
  observeEvent(input$make_plot, {
    current_id <- paste0("plot_", counter_plots)
    # call the logic for one plot
    one_plot(id = current_id,
             x = x,
             y = y,
             type = input$plotType,
             breaks = input$breaks,
             break_counts = input$breakCount)
    # show the plot
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here",
             ui = one_plotUI(current_id))
    
    # update the counter
    counter_plots <<- counter_plots + 1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is close, but I'm looking for an answer that does something like this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-generate-plots-with-actionbutton/45739. The only problem is that this limits to 4 plots, but I would like to create more plots.

Comment: thanks for the clarification; see my edit how to solve this with a module

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to create an arbitrary number of plots.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(glue)

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("add_sepal_length", "Add Sepal.Length Histogram"),
                actionButton("add_sepal_width", "Add Sepal.Width Histogram"),
                uiOutput("plot_ui"))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  number_of_plots <- reactiveVal(0L)
  
  output$plot_ui <- renderUI({
    req(number_of_plots()>0)
    seq(number_of_plots(),1) %>% map(~plotOutput(glue("plot_{.}")))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_sepal_length,{
    output[[glue("plot_{number_of_plots() +1}")]] <- renderPlot(hist(iris$Sepal.Length))
    number_of_plots(number_of_plots() + 1L)
  })
  observeEvent(input$add_sepal_width,{
    output[[glue("plot_{number_of_plots() +1}")]] <- renderPlot(hist(iris$Sepal.Width))
    number_of_plots(number_of_plots() + 1L)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The basic idea is that you can use `renderPlot` to add to `ouput$` by string.  The `observeEvent` creates the plot on demand.  Put whatever plotting logic you want in here.  This takes care of the server part.  The UI is handled by a single `renderUI` which returns a list of `plotOutput`s.

My logic here is very simple.  I use a `map()` function which only needs to know the id.  You could do something fancy involving a whole lot of parameters.  One time I did a project where I had arbitrarily many `selectInput`s.  I stored the parameters in a tibble inside of a `reactiveVal` and used `pmap()` inside the `renderUI`.